# Change property of immutable type

Tags: c#, clone, immutability, icloneable

I have stored immutable types in a temporary CQRS read store (query/read side, in fact implemented by a simple List with abstraction access layer, I don't want to use a full blown document database at this point). These read stores contains items like the following:

```
public class SomeItem
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly string description;

    public SomeItem(string name, string description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return this.description; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the Name and in a 2nd Command the Description.
These changes should keep the current state, which means for the example above:

```
// initial state
var someItem = new SomeItem("name", "description");

// update name -> newName
someItem = new SomeItem("newName", someItem.Description);

// update description -> newDescription
someItem = new SomeItem(someItem.Name, "newDescription");
```

This does look error prone to me if you have several properties... you have to manage keeping the current state. I could add something like Clone() to every type but I think/hope there is something better out there that performs well and is easy to use, I don't want to write much repetive code (lazy programmer). Any suggestions how to improve the code above? The SomeItem class needs to stay immutable (transported through several different threads).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With C#9 we got the **with** operator for this purpose.

```
   public record Car
    {
        public string Brand { get; init; }   
        public string Color { get; init; }    
    }
    var car = new Car{ Brand = "BMW", Color = "Red" }; 
    var anotherCar = car with { Brand = "Tesla"};
```

> With-expressions When working with immutable data, a common pattern is
> to create new values from existing ones to represent a new state. For
> instance, if our person were to change their last name we would
> represent it as a new object that’s a copy of the old one, except with
> a different last name. This technique is often referred to as
> non-destructive mutation. Instead of representing the person over
> time, the record represents the person’s state at a given time. To
> help with this style of programming, records allow for a new kind of
> expression; the with-expression:

[News in C#9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9)

**NOTE**
With operator is only supported by records.

> **Records** At the core of classic object-oriented programming is the idea that an object has strong identity and encapsulates mutable state
> that evolves over time. C# has always worked great for that, But
> sometimes you want pretty much the exact opposite, and here C#’s
> defaults have tended to get in the way, making things very laborious.

[Recods in C#9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types)

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, there's no simple way in C#. F# has the `with` keyword, and you could have a look at lenses, but it's all somewhat tedious in C#. The best I can give you is something like this:

```
class SomeItem
{
  private readonly string name;
  private readonly string description;

  public SomeItem(string name, string description)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public SomeItem With
    (
      Option<string> name = null,
      Option<string> description = null
    )
  {
    return new SomeItem
      (
        name.GetValueOrDefault(this.name), 
        description.GetValueOrDefault(this.description)
      );
  }
}
```

This allows you to do the updates like

```
var newItem = oldItem.With(name: "My name!");
```

I've used this approach with extension methods and T4s to great effect, but even when you write the code manually, it's reasonably reliable - if you add a new field, you must add it to the `With` as well, so it works quite well.

There's a few more approaches if you are willing to tolerate runtime code generation and reducing type safety, but that's kind of going against the grain IMO.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is commonly called the **with operator**:

```
// returns a new immutable object with just the single property changed
someItem = { someItem with Name = "newName" };
```

Unfortunately, unlike F#, C# does not have such an operator (yet?).

Other C# developers are missing this feature as well, which is why [someone wrote a Fody extension to do exactly that](http://mikhail.io/2016/05/tweaking-immutable-objects-with-csharp-and-fody/):

- https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/With.Fody

Here's another approach, which implements an `UpdateWith` method manually but requires an `Option<T>` helper class. [Luaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789743/87698) describes this approach in more detail:

- [Implementing F#-inspired "with" updates for immutable classes in C#](http://www.productiverage.com/implementing-f-sharp-inspired-with-updates-for-immutable-classes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It's coming! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#with-expressions

Comment: This is the up-to-date way to go now. Thx for pointing this out if someone comes across this question.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple solution

I also thought about this question. Record's are not suitable for my purposes, since it is necessary to interact with EF Core.

I suggest a simple and low-cost way:

- add a copy constructor to the class;
- Make properties that change during cloning available for initialization;
- clone an object with a change through the copy constructor with an initialization list:

```
var a = new SomeItem("name", "abracadabra");
var b = new SomeItem(a) {Description="descr"};
```

### Simple code

```
var a = new SomeItem("name", "abracadabra");
var b = new SomeItem(a) {Description="descr"};

public class SomeItem
{
    private string name;
    private string description;

    public SomeItem(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }

    public SomeItem(SomeItem another): this(another.Name, another.Description)
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        init => name = value;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => description;
        init => description = value;
    }
}
```

## Extended solution

If the final type is not known at compile time, then this approach is easy to extend. Let's say there is a class "ValueObject" whose derived types we need to clone.

**Note**: I apologize for the incorrect translation in some places. English version obtained using google.translate

### Additional code

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Light.GuardClauses;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using static DotNext.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionBuilder;

using ValueObject = Company.Domain....;


/// <summary>
/// The plagiarizer creates a copy of the object with a change in its individual properties using an initializer
/// </summary>
/// <remarks> The foreign object must define a copy constructor, and mutable members must support initialization </remarks>
public struct Plagiarist {
    /// <summary>
    /// Object to be copied
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _alienObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// Type <see cref="_alienObject" />
    /// </summary>
    private Type _type => _alienObject.GetType();

    /// <summary>
    /// Object parsing Expression
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ParsingInitializationExpression _parser = new();

    public Plagiarist(object alienObject) {
        _alienObject = alienObject.MustNotBeNullReference();
        if (!CopyConstructorIs())
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type {_type.FullName} must implement a copy constructor");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does the object we want to plagiarize have a copy constructor?
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True - there is a copy constructor, otherwise - false</returns>
    [Pure]
    private bool CopyConstructorIs() {
        return _type.GetConstructor(new[] { _type }) is not null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a copy of a foreign object with a change in its individual properties using an initializer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initializer">
    /// <see cref="Expression" /> create an object with initialization of those fields,
    /// which need to be changed:
    /// <code>() => new T() {Member1 = "Changed value1", Member2 = "Changed value2"}</code>
    /// or <see cref="Expression" /> create an anonymous type with initialization of those fields
    /// that need to be changed:
    /// <code>() => new {Member1 = "Changed value1", Member2 = "Changed value2"}</code>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Pure]
    public object Plagiarize(Expression<Func<object>> initializer) {
        var (newValues, constructParam) = _parser.ParseInitialization(initializer);
        var constrCopies = _type.New(_alienObject.Const().Convert(_type));

        Expression plagiarist = (newValues.Count, constructParam.Count) switch {
            (> 0, _) => Expression.MemberInit(constrCopies, newValues.Values),
            (0, > 0) => Expression.MemberInit(constrCopies, ConstructorInInitializationList(constructParam).Values),
            _ => constrCopies
        };

        var plagiarize = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(plagiarist).Compile();

        return plagiarize();
    }

    [Pure]
    public Dictionary<string, MemberAssignment> ConstructorInInitializationList(
        Dictionary<string, Expression> constructorParameters) {
        Dictionary<string, MemberAssignment> initializer = new();
        const BindingFlags flagReflections = BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
        var allProperties = _type.GetProperties(flagReflections);
        var allFields = _type.GetFields(flagReflections);

        foreach (var memberName in constructorParameters.Keys) {
            var property = allProperties.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name ==memberName);
            var field = allFields.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == memberName);
            (MemberInfo member, Type memberType) = (property, field) switch {
                ({ }, _) => (property, property.PropertyType),
                (null, { }) => ((MemberInfo)field, field.FieldType),
                _ => throw new ArgumentException($"{_type.FullName} does not contain member {memberName}")
            };

            initializer[memberName] = Expression.Bind(member, constructorParameters[memberName].Convert(memberType));
        }

        return initializer;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Template "Visitor" for traversing the expression tree in order to highlight
    /// initialization expression and constructor
    /// </summary>
    private class ParsingInitializationExpression : ExpressionVisitor {
        private Dictionary<string, MemberAssignment>? _initializer;
        private Dictionary<string, Expression>? _initializerAnonym;

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the expression tree and returns the initializer and constructor parameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="initializer"><see cref="Expression" /> to parse</param>
        /// <returns> tuple of initializer and constructor</returns>
        public ParsedInitialization ParseInitialization(Expression initializer) {
            _initializer = new Dictionary<string, MemberAssignment>();
            _initializerAnonym = new Dictionary<string, Expression>();
            Visit(initializer);
            return new ParsedInitialization(_initializer, _initializerAnonym);
        }

        protected override MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node) {
            _initializer![node.Member.Name] = node;
            return base.VisitMemberAssignment(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node) {
            foreach (var (member, value) in node.Members?.Zip(node.Arguments) ??
                                             Array.Empty<(MemberInfo First, Expression Second)>())
                _initializerAnonym![member.Name] = value;

            return base.VisitNew(node);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Type to return values from method <see cref="ParseInitialization" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Initializer"></param>
        /// <param name="ConstructorParameters"></param>
        public record struct ParsedInitialization(Dictionary<string, MemberAssignment> Initializer,
            Dictionary<string, Expression> ConstructorParameters);
    }
}

public static class ValueObjectPlagiarizer{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a copy of the object with a change in its individual properties using an initializer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="alien">Object to be plagiarized</param>
    /// <param name="initializer">
    /// <see cref="Expression" /> creating an object of type <typeparamref name="T" />
    /// with initialization of those fields that need to be changed:
    /// <code>ob.Plagiarize(() => new T() {Member1 = "Changed value1", Member2 = "Changed value2"})</code>
    /// or <see cref="Expression" /> create an anonymous type with initialization of those fields that need to be changed:
    /// <code>ob.Plagiarize(() => new {Member1 = "Changed value1", Member2 = "Changed value2"})</code>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>plagiarism of the object</returns>
    public static object Plagiarize<T>(this ValueObject alien, Expression<Func<T>> initializer)
        where T : class {
        var bodyReduced = initializer.Convert<object>();
        var initializerReduced = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(bodyReduced, initializer.Parameters);

        return new Plagiarist(alien).Plagiarize(initializerReduced);
    }
}
```

### Usages

If SomeItem is a descendant of ValueObject

```
ValueObject a = new SomeItem("name", "abracadabra");

// via type constructor
var b = (SomeItem)a.Plagiarize(()=>new SomeItem(null){Description="descr"});
// anonymous type 
var c = (SomeItem)a.Plagiarize(()=>new{Description="descr"});

b.Description.Should().Be("descr"); //true
c.Description.Should().Be("descr"); //true
```

Answer (score -2):

If what you want to do is (as you commented) update the name of an existing object, a readonly property might be bad design. 
Otherwise if its really a new object you want to create, you might want your class to implement some interface with a 'Dispose' method.

Comment: That's not what he wants. He wants to use immutable data types and create updated versions of the data in a reasonably simple manner. This is quite typical in the immutable/functional programming world. The point is he never wants to change the original object (just like you don't want to change a `string`, for example).